# Italic correction in tcbtheorem

Tags: tcolorbox, emphasis, italic-correction

I have redefined the `\emph` command to give bold and slanted text

```latex
\DeclareEmphSequence{\bfseries\boldmath\slshape, \itshape}
```

however, this appears to affect horizontal spacing on the line which `\emph` is used. I only noticed this effect for multiline `tcbtheorem` environments with a long enough title. For example, if the theorem is numbered or has an optional title.

I tried using italic correction, but nothing has worked to make the spacing consistent. Also, I understand that many disapprove of using bold `\emph`, I may define a new command specifically for use in definitions.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{definition}
{Definition}{
    enhanced,
    detach title, fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
    coltitle=gray!70!black,
    before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}
}{def}

\DeclareEmphSequence{\bfseries\boldmath\slshape, \itshape}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{definition}{}{}
    Suppose \(\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}\) is open. Then a function \(f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\) is \emph{holomorphic} if it is complex differentiable at every point \(z \in \Omega\).
\end{definition}

\begin{definition*}{}{}
    Suppose \(\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}\) is open. Then a function \(f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\) is \emph{holomorphic} if it is complex differentiable at every point \(z \in \Omega\).
\end{definition*}

\begin{definition*}{test}{}
    Suppose \(\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}\) is open. Then a function \(f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\) is \emph{holomorphic} if it is complex differentiable at every point \(z \in \Omega\).
\end{definition*}

\begin{definition}{}{}
    Suppose \(\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}\) is open. Then a function \(f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\) is \emph{holomorphic}\dots
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please, make the code snippet into a full (minimal) document we can play with. It's impossible to guess how you build the `definition` environment.

Comment: It would help if you provided an example. looking at the image it doesn't seem related to italic correction just that the different font made the word wider and changed the line breaking resulting in a loose line with white space stretched, so just a result of the font choice and text width (about which you have given no information)

Comment: note _all_ the white space on that line is stretched, not just the space around the bold slanted font.

Comment: I am working on the minimal document right now, thank you for comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try it without `\emph` you will see `differentiable` just squeezes on to the line, with compressed spacing, but `\emph` and bold makes the line longer and it doesn't fit and tex is choosing to stretch space rather than put a hyphen on the penultimate line of a paragraph.

Simplest here is to force hyphenation while using `\linebreak` (not `\\` ) to force a justified line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{definition}
{Definition}{
    enhanced,
    detach title, fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
    coltitle=gray!70!black,
    before upper={\tcbtitle\quad}
}{def}

\DeclareEmphSequence{\bfseries\boldmath\slshape, \itshape}

\showhyphens{differentiable}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}


\begin{definition}{}{}
    Suppose \(\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}\) is open. Then a function \(f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\) is {holomorphic} if it is complex differentiable at every point \(z \in \Omega\).
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}{}{}
    Suppose \(\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}\) is open. Then a function \(f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\) is \emph{holomorphic} if it is complex differentiable at every point \(z \in \Omega\).
\end{definition}


\begin{definition}{}{}
    Suppose \(\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}\) is open. Then a function \(f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\) is \emph{holomorphic} if it is complex differ-\linebreak entiable at every point \(z \in \Omega\).
\end{definition}




\end{document}
```